# Set mysql values from radio buttons in html form

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I want two radio buttons on a webpage (written in php) representing "yes" and "no". When I load the page I want it to fetch a value from a mysql db and set the corresponding radio button. And when I click on the other button, I want it to update the database and reload the page.

I'm trying to do this with a simple html form, but no luck. The code I have so far (that is not working at all :( is:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT challenge_me FROM contestants WHERE id=$id";
    $res = (mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql, $db)));
    $challenge_me = $res["challenge_me"];

}else{
    $sql = "UPDATE contestants SET challenge_me='" . $_POST['YesNo'] . "' WHERE id='$id'";
    if(!mysql_query($sql, $db))
        echo mysql_error(), "<br/>Query '$sql'";
    $challenge_me = $_POST['YesNo'];
}

    echo'<form method="post" action="' . $PHP_SELF . '">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="submit">';          
if($challenge_me == 1){
    echo'<input type="radio" name="YesNo" value="1" onClick="this.form.submit();" checked>Yes ';
    echo'<input type="radio" name="YesNo" value="0" onClick="this.form.submit();">No ';
}else{
    echo'<input type="radio" name="YesNo" value="1" onClick="this.form.submit();">Yes ';
    echo'<input type="radio" name="YesNo" value="0" onClick="this.form.submit();" checked>No ';
}
echo'</form>';
```

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but you shouldn't be using string concatenation to build an SQL query. Your script is currently vulnerable to SQL injection based on using `$_POST['YesNo']` without at least escaping it or using mysql statements.

Comment: How is it not working?  What is happening?

Comment: Hmm, seems like I solved it. It didn't work if the hidden post was named "submit". That prevented the form to do anything when I clicked on the radio buttons. Renaming it to something else worked well...

And thanks for the comment about sql injection!

Answer (score 1):

Your script doesnt seem to define $id, where does $id get its value from? That could be the source of your problem. Your script might not be passing any value in $id

Comment: also, $PHP_SELF is blank i'm assuming. I think you are trying to use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. this probably isn't affe4cting the code however because leaving the action blank will automatically submit the form to itself.

Comment: Well, $id comes as an argument to the function (I removed a couple of lines of code that I thought wasn't interesting for my question).

Comment: @faximan have you resolved the problem yet? have you tried @dqhendricks suggestion, that is another possible cause

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It works now, all that was needed was to change the name of the hidden input from "submit" to "submitValue".Guess "submit" is some kind of reserved word.